# Why it is assigning a garbage value to variable 'calc'?

Tags: c++, oop

This program gives a garbage value to the variable `calc`.

Can anyone help me? What is the problem here?

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class trial {
public:
    int m1;
    int m2;
    int calc = m1 + m2;
    void setdata(int a1, int a2) {
        m1 = a1;
        m2 = a2;
    }
    void getcalc(){
        cout << "Sum of m1 & m2 is " << calc << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    trial t1;
    t1.setdata(3, 8);
    t1.getcalc();
    system("pause>0");
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Sum of m1 & m2 is -1717986920
```

Comment: You set calc `    int calc = m1 + m2;` with the uninitialized values.
You want to set calc after you set m1 and m2

Comment: `int calc = m1 + m2;` the calculation happens when `trial` is constructed before `m1` and `m2` have values. Remember c++ executes this as a 1 time assignment. Its not like a spreadsheet where a variable is recalculated when the values change.

Comment: Delete `int calc = m1 + m2;` and do the calculation in `void getcalc(){` For a better class design you may want to remove `void setdata(int a1, int a2) {` and instead add a constructor to your trial class that initializes `m1` and `m2` on construction.

Comment: This question might be better if you explained why you think `calc` should not have garbage in it? At what point do you assign it a non-garbage value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how you defined `calc`.

When a object `trial` is initialized, `m1+m2` is assigned to `calc`, but `m1` and `m2` are not initialized themselves (they contain 'garbage').

When `setdata()` is called, two user-provided integers are assigned to `m1` and `m2`, but `calc` is unchanged, thus the 'garbage' in the output.

You need to update `calc` by adding `calc = m1 + m2;` in `setdata()`.

Answer (score 0):

You are never calculating the sum at first place ...

```
void setdata(int a1, int a2) {
        m1 = a1;
        m2 = a2;
        calc = m1 + m2;
    }
```

but always initialize the member variables, you are not initializing the m1 and m2, hence garbage values which is assigned by the compiler.